# Qt5.5 XML processing using QDom

Tags: c++, qt5.5

I'm using the QDom classes to process an XML file, I want the attributes to be processed in the order they are defined in the XML file, this is important.  However it seems the order of the attributes in the 'QDomNamedNodeMap' is different.

Is there any way to ensure the order is as defined in the XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written my own classes that read the file and process the nodes and attributes, as per my requirement the attributes are kept in the same order they are presented in the file.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't rely on order of attributes in XML, by specifications. This could be the reason your library read them in a different order that the literal one. Even if you find a way, you should not trust it: what about if someone else generates the XML to feed your program? See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) more about the specifications.
Maybe a change in the design can help you: what about nesting some nodes? Nesting nodes sequence is deterministic.

Comment: I'm fast thinking I'll have to write my own handlers.

Comment: The XML I've written allows attributes to use macro references to other attributes hench why the order is important, but the author can write the XML in any way they wish as long as when one reference to another is implemented the reference is not before the other.

Comment: @SPlatten better not: if someone else generates the xml for you, you will be in a trouble as well ( he can generate with attributes in a different order )

Comment: If another is writing the XML then they will do so according to my specification for the application processing it.

Comment: What I want is to read the attributes in the order they are presented in the file.

Comment: @SPlatten XML specifications, is not yours :) If you cant write the specification with an XSD ( schema definition ) your specification is not valid in term of xml.

Comment: I can write a specification to define the usage of the XML in any way I see fit, this content of the file has nothing to do with anyone outside of the organisation using it.